# Multiple generic parameters in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I want to have function in swift which takes two parameters which must have some base class and each confront to different protocol.

```
class func createContainerViewController<T:UIViewController, U:UIViewController>(withCenterViewController centerViewController: T, andLeftViewController leftViewController: U) -> ContainerViewController where T: CenterViewController, U: SidePanelViewController
```

But whenever I try to use the method like this:

```
let left: SidePanelViewController = UIStoryboard.leftViewController()!
let center: EventsListViewController = UIStoryboard.eventsListViewController()!

let containerViewController = ContainerViewController.createContainerViewController(withCenterViewController: center, andLeftViewController: left)
```

Xcode gives me an error

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Both variables center and left are instances of classes which inherits from UIViewController and confronts to desired protocol for T or U.

Usage in createContainerViewController function:

```
let container = ContainerViewController()

container.centerViewController = centerViewController
var centerViewController = container.centerViewController as! CenterViewController
centerViewController.delegate = container

container.leftViewController = leftViewController
var leftViewController = container.leftViewController as! SidePanelViewController
leftViewController.delegate = container

return container
```

Comment: Your two lines of code are fine as long as `CenterViewController` and `SIdePanelViewController` are both subclasses of `UIViewController`.  How are you using `T` and `U` in the body of the function? (Also, try it in XCode 8 with swift 3 if you haven't already)

Comment: I'm using Xcode 8 and Swift 3. And center and left are both subclasses of UIViewController and implementing correct protocols...

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
protocol CenterViewController {}
protocol SidePanelViewController {}

class Center: UIViewController, CenterViewController {}
class Left: UIViewController, SidePanelViewController {}

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let center = Center()
        let left = Left()
        let _ = ContainerViewController.createContainerViewController(withCenterViewController: center, andLeftViewController: left)
    }

    class func createContainerViewController<T:UIViewController, U:UIViewController>(withCenterViewController centerViewController: T, andLeftViewController leftViewController: U) -> ContainerViewController where T: CenterViewController, U: SidePanelViewController {
        return ContainerViewController()
    }
}
```

Comment: It builds for me in Xcode 8, what version of swift and xcode are you using?